# How to truncate the string into required length in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I am having a string which contains more the 25 characters;

```
NSString *str = @"This is the string to be truncated to 15 characters only";
```

In the above string I need only the 15 characters to be stored in another variable after truncation.

can anyone suggest me how to do this?
Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
str = [str substringToIndex: MIN(15, [str length])];
```

Comment: So it would be a good idea to check the length before attempting this... if ([str length] > 15) { str = [str substringToIndex:15];}

Answer (score 26):

Or,

`str = [str substringToIndex: MIN(15, [str length])];`

Now you are safely truncating to 15 or less.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add `substringToIndex:15`... you won't get a crash if the string is too short or nil.